# Rails Assets: Custom Application.css.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I know that in order to precompile your assets you do the following

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

which will take your `application.css.sass` in `app/assets/styesheets` and generate `application-xxxxx.css` in your `public/assets` directory

My question, what if you have a custom `application_custom.css.scss` How to precompile it to be used by production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include that file in the `application.css.scss` manifest file.

Add the following line in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`:

```
*= require application_custom
```

You can also specify additional assets to precompile by adding them to `config.assets.precompile += %w( ... )` in your environment configuration, e.g. `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: Can't I have it separate? have another file under public/assets/application_custom

Comment: You shouldn't be placing such assets inside `public/assets` because when you run `rake assets:clean` that directory gets deleted.  But about your other question, yes you can specify additional assets to precompile by adding them to `config.assets.precompile += %w( ... )` in e.g. `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: on another note, for some reason whenever I run rake assets:clean it only deletes 4 files out of 100 which is very weird.

Comment: Can you add the config.assets.precompile to your solution so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: @Newbie, updated my answer.  Also what is your rails version?  I'd like to find out about why your `rake assets:clean` does not remove all the assets directory.

Comment: Should I like open a new question regarding that?

Comment: That'll be better as that will get everybody's attention, make sure to tag it with rails 4, and include your environment.rb file in the question